# how to open pdf file in jupyter file browser?

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook

I would like to open a pdf file using the jupyter notebook's file browser. However, when I click, it always opens a new tab and shows a dark screen.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to open a pdf in Jupyter? If you just want to read it, you could use a pdf reader. Are you trying to edit it?

Comment: No @Simon.S.A. I want to read the file in the browser itself as I am doing 2-3 courses together and they all have pdf files in them. If it stays in the same window so it eases out the process.

Answer (score 4):

I spent a couple of minutes looking for a workaround for this and found a github [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3652) in the jupyter project where OP discovered that the [issue is resolved by installing the PDF viewer plugin to Chrome](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3652#issuecomment-413036698)

I just installed it and I am now seeing PDF's from my notebook in Chrome.

Comment: In case it takes time for you to find the extension, [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much easier.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open a pdf file using the jupyter filebrowser, you need to use Firefox - Google Chrome blocks it.

Alternatively, to open the pdf inside a jupyter notebook cell, you can use IFrame - but again, it doesn't work for Chrome.

```
from IPython.display import IFrame, display
#filepath = "http://wikipedia.org" # works with websites too!
filepath = "file.pdf"
IFrame(filepath, width=700, height=400)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate it and according to you I'll have to change the code every-time I need to open one!! Isn't there an easy way as I just need to read them.

Comment: can you explain more how you would read them: above solution opens them in jupyter notebook, provided you give the right file name. Do you mean you want to open pdf from the jupyter directory file tree in a new window?